# Worksheet_Change Target.Address on specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automatically hide/unhide rows on sheet2 when cell c9 changes on sheet1.

I have my Hide/Unhide Rows toggle all set up.

My worksheet change works when the target cell is on sheet2 but does not when I attempt to set the target cell to sheet1 (As is shown in my code below).

Module1 Code:

```
Sub Hide_Rows_Toggle()

Dim r As Range

For Each r In Columns(2).Cells
    If r.Value = "X" Then
        r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Sheet2 Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$C$9") Then
    Call Hide_Rows_Toggle
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. You are saying procedure should run if cell C9 changes on Sheet1, then the worksheet_change event procedure should be on Sheet1 not Sheet 2.. Also you are checking  `Target.Address` a string with `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$C$9")` a cell value. You can change it to `Target.Address = "$C$9"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I'm home, and have tested the following;

You haven't qualified a Workbook or Worksheet object in your `Hide_Rows_Toggle()` sub. As such it is implicitly referencing the `ActiveWorksheet`

Per [Worksheet.Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.columns) documentation:

> Using the **Columns** property without an object qualifier is equivalent to using **ActiveSheet.Columns**. If the active document isn't a worksheet, the **Columns** property fails.

The `Worksheet_Change` event is Worksheet specific, meaning, the event is triggered on each worksheet independantly - If you make a change on `Sheet1` the event won't trigger on `Sheet2` etc.

You should do the following:

1. Move your `Worksheet_Change` event to the module for `Sheet1`, where the change is happening.
2. Qualify your target worksheet (at least) in your `Hide_Rows_Toggle` Subroutine like so:

Qualify your range in your sub like so:

```
Sub Hide_Rows_Toggle()

Dim r As Range

For Each r In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(2).Cells
    If r.Value = "X" Then
        r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

This ensures the rows will only be hidden on Sheet2, otherwise it will always target the *ActiveSheet* which has to be the sheet you made the change in.

Lastly, It's a little unclear exactly what you are attempting to evaluate in your Worksheet_Change event.

Currently you are looking to see if the `Target.Address` is equal to the `Value` in Cell `$C$9` on `Sheet1`. This is because [the default member for the Range object is Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)). So it will only return true if you are setting a cell reference in `$C$9` to dictate which cell triggers the sub.

If you are intending to run `Hide_Rows_Toggle` when the value in `$C$9` is changed, you will need to add the `.Address` property to your range - `If Target.Address = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$C$9").Address` - or - simply change it to a string to match the address like `If Target.Address = "$C$9" Then`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Also, do you happen to know how I can have multiple target addresses, say C9 and C11

Comment: @mjhol Do you mean both cells are changed (at the same time) or one or the other?

Comment: @mjhol I think you mean one or the other, in that case, use the [Or operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/or-operator). E.g `If Target.Address = "A1" Or Target.Address = "B9" Then`. P.s any reason you unmarked it as accepted if it resolved your question...?

Comment: I suggest if you are working across multiple sheets, ensure you understand the principle of qualifying your objects that way you will avoid unexpected changes in unexpected places. 

Answer (score 2):

In `ThisWorkbook`:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" And Target.Address = "$C$9" Then
        Call Hide_Rows_Toggle
    End If
End Sub
```